# position vs time to position vs velocity

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a fifth order polynomial function of time to find displacement at time $t$. say $x(t) = a + bt + ct^2 + \cdots + ft^5$,

so  I can have velocity vs time function as

$$v(t) = b + 2ct + \cdots + 5ft^4,$$

I want to write velocity as a function of position.

i.e. find $v(x)$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fifth degree polynomial, you have potentially 5 roots. Finding the velocity as a function of position would be impractical as you could have a many-to-many function, thus creating ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know that position is always positive and strictly increasing. Can this be used to eliminate some roots ?

Comment: In that case, you should be able to find an inverse position function ($t(x)$) to find time as a function of position. Then substitute that into your $v(t)$ equation to find $v(t(x))$. Finding the inverse of a high degree polynomial may be difficult, but after that, you should be able to substitute/simplify with ease.

Comment: I'd say "a fifth-degree polynomial" rather than "a fifth order polynomial".

Comment: I was following the wording of the question, but you're completely correct. I'll edit my answer.